# Как по умолчанию задать рабочую директорию в VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

В студии рабочая директория `$(ProjectDir)` можно ли сделать так чтобы она по умолчанию была `$(TargetDir)` и не нужно было бы каждый раз лезть в настройки?

Comment: Думаю, что лучше уточнить версию и указать какие настройки Вы изменяете.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, но думаю в любой будет одинаково. В проекте есть есть вкладка "Debugging" в ней "WorkingDirectory"